# Are there any more time-efficient ways to solve a matrix equation than with SparseArray and LinearSolve?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I am trying to solve a matrix equation, with the matrix being tridiagonal. The problem I am having is that a message keeps appearing that I don't have enough memory. Here is the code:

```
n = 10109;(*matrix dimension*)

a = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1,Band[{2, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}](*the tridiagonal matrix*)

f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x + 1, x <= 0}, {-x + 1, x > 0}}](*initial condition, just for constructing the right-hand side vector*)

g = Table[f[i], {i, -1 + 2/(n + 1), 1 - 2/(n + 1), 2/(n + 1)}];(*the vector*)

u = LinearSolve[a, g];(*the solution I need*)
```

Actualy what I need is only

```
Norm[u,1]
```

and

```
u[5055].
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might make sense to write an explicit Gaussian elimination tailored to banded matrices. If `LinearSolve` is running out of memory it may be doing something less efficient than that. (I don't know why it would do otherwise, I'm just guessing based on the reported symptom.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Interestingly, the exact solution can be obtained in (perhaps) acceptable 30 seconds by breaking it up into `ff=LinearSolve[a];ff[g]`.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

The speed issue in this case was actually a simple matter: the matrices had only exact numbers, and that slowed the solution down to the extent that it became impractical.

But when I converted the matrix `a` and the vector `g` to machine precision, the solution was found almost instantaneously:

First I repeat your definitions:

```
n = 10109;(*matrix dimension*)a = 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, 
   Band[{2, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}];(*the tridiagonal matrix*)

f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x + 1, x <= 0}, {-x + 1, 
    x > 0}}](*initial condition,just for constructing the right-hand \
side vector*)

g = Table[
  f[i], {i, -1 + 2/(n + 1), 1 - 2/(n + 1), 2/(n + 1)}];(*the vector*)
```

Here is the simple solution based on converting to machine precision:

```
vv = LinearSolve[N[a], N[g]];

ListPlot[vv]
```

[image: new solution]

The absolute error is now much smaller than with my initial approach based on a differential-equation approximation.

```
diff2 = a.vv - g;

Max[Abs[diff2]]

(* ==> 5.82634*10^-9 *)
```

**If exact numbers are needed**

In case you don't want only machine-precision results, you will have to accept a more time-consuming calculation. But it can still be done:

```
ff = LinearSolve[a];

Timing[ww = ff[SparseArray[g]];]

(* ==>  {27.6843, Null} *)
```

Leaving out the `SparseArray` in the last command doesn't make a big difference, but it also doesn't hurt:

```
diff3 = a.ww - g;

Max[Abs[diff3]]

(* ==> 0 *)
```

This is therefore an **exact solution**, requiring less than half a minute of patience. It works by breaking the solution process into two steps. First get a `LinearSolveFunction` object that is independent of the right-hand side `g`, and then apply that function to the specific `g`. This sequence is still kind of slow, but *much* faster than the single `LinearSolve[a,g]` (which I never ran to completion).

I'll keep the previous approach below, because it's perhaps useful to observe the special nature of the matrix in this question.

**Previous approximate solution**

The matrix that you're dealing with is so large that it's best treated in a continuum approximation. This means you go from the discrete solution vector to a continuos function which you can find by solving a differential equation that is the continuous form of the matrix equation.

In your case, that's really easy to do because the matrix `a` is the finite-difference approximation to a second derivative operator. So here is how the problem can be solved.

Define a continuous right-hand side for our equation in terms of the function `f`, and call it `h`. It has the same domain `1,...n` as represented by the vector `g` which it is supposed to replace. Then solve the differential equation that is equivalent to the matrix equation:

```
h[x_] := f[-1 + 2/(n + 1) + 2 (x - 1)/(n + 1)]

s[x_] = y[x] /. 
   First@DSolve[D[y[x], x, x] == h[x], y[x], x] /. {C[1] -> 0, 
   C[2] -> 0}
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{x^3}{30330} & x \le 5055 \\
>  -\frac{x^3}{30330}+x^2-5055 x+8517675 & \text{True} \\
> \end{cases}$$

Here, two integration constants `C[1], C[2]` arise, corresponding to homogeneous solutions. I choose them to be zero.

Now test the solution by sampling the solution of `DSolve` at discrete points and applying the matrix to it:

```
u = Table[s[x], {x, 1, n}];

ListPlot[Most[a.u]]
```

[image: testing]

Compare this to the `ListPlot` of the original right-hand side vector:

```
ListPlot[g]
```

[image: testing]

The output looks the same, except that I had to throw out the right-most element of the vector `a.u` from the differential equation because boundary effects cause it to deviate too much. To be more quantitative, here are the differences:

```
diff = Most[a.u - g];

N[Max[Abs[diff]]]

(* ==> 0.0000659413 *)
```

Within this error estimate, we can be confident that the following results answer your questions:

```
N[Norm[u, 1]]

(* ==> 7.53367*10^10 *)

u[[5055]]

(* ==> 8517675/2 *)
```

Here is what the solution vector looks like:

```
ListPlot[u]
```

[image: solution]

This solution looks very different from the exact vector obtained earlier. But this is only one of the possible solutions to the differential equations, because a second-order differential equation always leads to two integration constants which I chose arbitrarily. To make the continuos equation yield the same solution plot as the discrete equation, I have to choose `C[1] -> 0` and `C[2] -> -(774869930101/306605970)`.

Comment: Interesting - any idea why breaking the LinearSolve into two steps helps so much?

Comment: @ala10 Sorry - I don't. I think it was an empirical observation on what is otherwise a black box, unfortunately...